# Check overlap 2 recurring appointments?

Tags: java, algorithm, calendar, overlap

I was recently asked this question in an interview.

Problem Statement: You are given 2 recurring appointments. Each appointment contains a required start time, an optional end time and a recurrence rule(required). 
All recurrence rules are listed below:

- Daily: example: Every 2 days
- Weekly: example: Every 3 weeks on Tuesday
- Monthly: example: Every 2 months on day 17/Monthly on the third Tuesday
- Yearly: example: Every 2 years on April 17

You have to check overlap 2 above events.

I have a solution for daily recurrence.

First appointment: start time: 1/3/2018(dd/MM/YYYY), endTime: , recurrence rule: Every 2 days

Second appointment: start time: 3/3/2018(dd/MM/YYYY), endTime: , recurrence rule: Every 3 days

The next days of the first appointment: 1 + 2*x

The next days of the second appointment: 3 + 3*y

if two overlap appointments: 1 + 2*x = 3 + 3*y <=> 2*x - 3*y = 2;

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for(x=1; ; x++){
   for(y=1; ; y++){
       if(2*x - 3*y == 2){
          break;
       }
   }
}

(x,y) = (4,2).
```

Two appointments are overlapping on 9/1/2018

If two appointments have no end time, my loop to find (x,y) will not have expression-2. So, it's very bad if the equation is impossible to solve.

Can anyone have another solution for this?

Comment: You might want to read about linear Diophantine equations - to get general solution or discover that solution does not exist

Comment: It’s complicated, but probably not impossible. No one can give a full solution in an interview. My guess is they expect you to say something about the challenges and how to go about them. Like if one is on Mondays and the other on Thursday, you can already tell there is no overlap.

Comment: Are they one-day all-day events? So end time means when the recurrence ends, not when the individual appointment ends??

Comment: tks @MBo. I have read about linear Diophantine equations. its good for me.

Comment: tks @Ole V.V. It’s very very complicated for me. Too many problems

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to answering on stack overflow, so hopefully this makes sense:

Weeks essentially boil down to groups of 7 days
Years essentially boil down to groups of 12 months

We cannot say that a month or a year is a number of days because month lengths vary (February 28/29 vs March 31) and there are leap years to watch out for too.

This means that if the first appointment is recurring in days/weeks and the second appointment is recurring in months/years, they must overlap at some point. I don't have a formal proof for this, but I assume in some math textbook there's pages of theory on this. Now the date where appointments match can be found with an algorithm similar to what you coded above. In practicality it might be wise to use a library for dates because of leap years, months, etc. but in an interview I don't think they expect that from you.

In the case where both appointments are from the same "family" (both can be measured in days or both can be measured in months), the only case where they won't ever happen on the same day is if the recurrence of the first appointment (n) is a multiple of the recurrence of the second appointment (m) or vice versa.

```
if(n<=m && n%m==0 || m<=n && m%n==0) {
    //they won't happen on the same day/month
}
```

One last thing to watch out for is that if both appointments reoccur monthly/annually, then the day of the month needs to match - otherwise they won't ever happen on the same day.

At least that's how I see it. Hope this helped :)

Comment: There may be missing a corner case or two, but the ideas are fine. Like if one recurrence is a multiple of the other, but they have the same start day — then there certainly is an overlap.

Comment: tks @David M for your solution.